# OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan SSLRead() return error -9841

Tags: macos, ssl, curl, https, terminal

After curl request in terminal to https website i had this error

```
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9841
```

curl --version

```
curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets
```

How to make curl work?

P.S I reinstalled curl by this command `brew install --with-openssl curl`

Comment: So, you could delete the question as an error is not reproducible as you states that after reboot everything works fine.

Comment: @lorond though he didn't identify the cause or provide a way to reproduce, it's still useful for others to know that rebooting fixes the issue. In the future, someone may find a better solution.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty I guess if simple reboot helped, there could be a numerous of reasons and most likely something just was misconfigured or loaded incorrectly. That happens. As this particular problem is not reproducible there is no reason to keep this question. Nobody could provide a better solution as nobody could be sure if it is a solution at all - no way to check it. Guessing about reasons is the best you can do. Also, reboot as a solution is off-topic as it has nothing to do with programming and as this is an actual solution, this question could also be off-topic.

Comment: @lorond I think you're right that this is off-topic, but I think it's the question itself...it's not a code question in the first place.

Comment: this question + answer helped me resolve my issue in an instant. This question should NOT be down voted or removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this same issue with Sierra and it seemed to be that even after running `brew install --with-openssl curl`, it still wan't being picked up by the path.

To begin, I had to force install the package with `brew install --force --with-openssl curl`

I then had to force link the new version of curl with `brew link --force curl`

After closing and reopening my terminal, it worked (this might have been what made the restart work with the above answer).

Comment: This fixed it for me ... if you already had `curl` installed outside of `brew`, ensure that the path `brew` installs `curl` to is returned by the `which curl` command

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this error...    In my case, "SSLRead" was a red herring..   The host was returning content-length: 0  (and no response body)

Apparently the host was rejecting requests missing some certain header...   for good measure, I added several headers to my request that the a web-browser sends..

`array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
),`

tada... no more SSLRead error